# Step Function: Wait - how long it can last?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I couldn't find any answers I am looking for on the AWS documentations.

Is it possible to execute 100,000 (approx) Step Functions and the state has WAIT until 3 months? The wait state will check every 30 minutes, otherwise it will exit state after 2 months.

The wait state will execute a lambda function - it will check if a field (dynamodb) has matched condition before carry on the next state.

I like to know if there is any limitation?

If WAIT state is not good approach, what is alternative?

Answer (score 6):

Yes your State Machine's (SM) `Wait` state can wait up to 1 year. However the number of SMs you intend to run for two months would be a very expensive solution.

You intend to run 100,000 SMs and each SM's Wait state will execute a lambda after every 30 min. There is a probability that all 100,000 SMs are running for two months.

Assuming all SMs are running for 2 months, total number of transactions will be:

1 SM = 96 transactions (Wait to Lambda, Lambda to Wait) per day. `5760 transactions in 2 months` per SM.

```
100,000 SM = 5760 * 100,000 = 576000000 transactions

First 4000 transactions are free so total transactions = 576000000 - 4000 = 575996000
```

$0.000025 per transactions after first 4000:

```
575996000 * 0.000025 = $14399.9 in two months.
```

$0.000025 is the [cheapest](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/), could be more depending on your region.

Also there is a risk of each SM execution history hitting the [limit of 25,000](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html).

I would suggest use either [CloudWatch schedule event to run a Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) every 30 min to verify the field in DynamoDB table or use [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to trigger Lambda for field verification. Once state is matched, you can then execute SMs. Both will be cheaper than step functions.

Answer (score 1):

[Executions can exist for up to 1 year](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-state-machine-executions) as per the AWS doucmentation. The maximum number of executions per account is 1,000,000.

Comment: So, a state can WAIT for 1 year? Nice.